# Restrict sale to guest member group?

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

My client wants guest and member pricing for products.

My initial thoughts were to create two sales one restricted to the members group and one restricted to a logged out (guest) group. It looks like sales can only be [restricted to member groups](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/control_panel_sales.html#restrict_to_member_groups).

How would I go about adding a discount to guests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I hacking ProductsService::apply_sales() to apply a discount before the `foreach ($this->get_active_sales() as $sale)` loop.

```
public function apply_sales(Product $product)
{
    // set initial option sale prices
    if (isset($product->modifiers)) {
        foreach ($product->modifiers as $modifier) {
            foreach ($modifier->options as $option) {
                $option->sale_price_mod = $option->opt_price_mod;
            }
        }
    }

    // find any sales which apply to this product
    $member_group_id = (int) $this->ee->session->userdata['group_id'];

    /**
     * HACK ^LG
     * Added 10% Discount Member Price
     */
    if($member_group_id) {
        $product->setPriceAttribute(store_round_currency($product->price - (10 * $product->price / 100)));
    }

    foreach ($this->get_active_sales() as $sale) {
        if ($this->sale_applies_to_product($sale, $product, $member_group_id)) {

            if ((float) $sale->per_item_discount) {
                $product->sale_price = store_round_currency($product->sale_price - $sale->per_item_discount);
            }

            if ((float) $sale->percent_discount) {
                $product->sale_price = store_round_currency($product->sale_price - ($sale->percent_discount * $product->sale_price / 100));

                // percentage discount also needs to be applied to loaded modifiers
                if (isset($product->modifiers)) {
                    foreach ($product->modifiers as $modifier) {
                        foreach ($modifier->options as $option) {
                            if ($option->opt_price_mod) {
                                $option->sale_price_mod = store_round_currency($option->sale_price_mod - ($sale->percent_discount * $option->sale_price_mod / 100), true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            $product->on_sale = true;
        }
    }

    return $product;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for putting this up. A great pointer to solving a similar problem in Store.